# Bash: need help with my bash script - Typeset

Tags: bash

I am reading some other developer script and I run across something I dont quite understand. Please help

```
typeset -u DOC_RET_CODE=`grep ^${PRNT_JOB_NAME}${SEQ_NUM} ${INPUT_FILE} |cut -c273-276`
if [ "${DOC_RET_CODE}" = "GOOD" ]
```

I look up typeset - u and it seems like it generate read-only variable, but not sure what it doing there. For `grep`, I usually pipe an input like `ls | grep test`, but grep by itself like this, I am not so sure. I know `cut -c273-276`, but 4 characters out from position 273-276. So what exactly does this script do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back-tick command (which would be better enclosed in `$(...)`) is grepping for a line starting with the print job name and sequence number from the input file, and then the 'cut' command is collecting columns 273-276 (4 characters).  The upper-case version of this value (`typeset -u`) is assigned to `$DOC_RET_CODE`.  The test line checks whether the document return code is GOOD and does something (not shown) if it is ... and maybe something else if the status is not good.

Answer (score 1):

```
> help typeset
typeset: typeset [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
    Set variable values and attributes.

    Obsolete.  See `help declare'.
> help declare
declare: declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    Set variable values and attributes.
    …
    Options which set attributes:
      -u        to convert NAMEs to upper case on assignment
```

In other words, this is making everything (the result of the `grep|cut` pipe) uppercase to avoid a `tr a-z A-Z` and allow a simple comparison against GOOD.

For your other question, `grep` is being run against a filename ${INPUT_FILE}.  You can run that command as is (after manually substituting the variables)

Answer (score 1):

It's not by itself; it's passed the argument `${INPUT_FILE}`, and it will read that file instead of its standard input.  The "useless use of `cat`" version would be `cat ${INPUT_FILE} | grep ...`.

Note that, per the earlier answer, `bash` has decided to drop compatibility and deprecate `typeset`.  `typeset` is largely compatible between `ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh`.